# Bottom Tab Bar in Android

Tags: android

I have made a bottom tab bar in the application.What I want is that when I click on that tab bar. A new Menu Type List should be `Opened/PopUp` and when i click on any of the list it should pop down Back.

I know how to create seperate activity but dont know how to create the Menu Type Pop-Up list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use OnClickListener on the **"Tab bar"**; implement the onClick(View) method to pop a new view which has your list. 
Do the same on list (may be you have to use performItemClick()) to go back to previous view or whichever view you want.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply create a menu and then open it onClick'ing the tab bar..
use the method `openOptionsMenu();` to do this.